# Paging with php

Tags: php, paging

I am working on making my results page look better, for the moment all my results are just on a 1 to 60 page format but like it to have a "previous" and "next" feature rather than this

```html
    function liensPage22($nbTotal,$marque,$modele,$etat,$budgetInit,$budgetFinal,$nrj,$bv,$cat,$couleur,$kmInit,$kmFinal,$annee,$id,$trie,$nbinit)
{
$nbPage=ceil($nbTotal/50);
echo'<table width="100%">';
echo'<p align="left"><strong><b>USE the search box to filter your query -'.$nbTotal.' - result</b>';
if ($nbTotal>1) { echo 's'; }
echo '</strong><b> - pages : </b>';
for ($i=1;$i<=$nbPage;$i++)
{
$nbinit2 = ($i-1)*10;
$page = $nbinit/10+1;
//echo '<b>page = </b>'.$page;
echo ($page==$i) ? $i.' ': '<a href="/lefthanddrivecars/result.php?marque='.$marque.'&amp;modele='.$modele.'&amp;budgetInit='.$budgetInit.'&amp;budgetFinal='.$budgetFinal.'&amp;nrj='.$nrj.'&amp;bv='.$bv.'&amp;cat='.$cat.'&amp;kmInit='.$kmInit.'&amp;kmFinal='.$kmFinal.'&amp;annee='.$annee.'&amp;nbinit='.$nbinit2.'">'.$i.'</a> ';
 
}
echo'</p>';
echo'</table>';
echo'<br />';
 
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Please start by formatting your code to be readable.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi I have tried this here

Comment: I'm new to this, I tried a code but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to first found it in which cases, previous and next page links are possible.

1) Previous -> not for first page.

2) Next -> not for last page.

Other than these two pages, we will show Prev and Next links.

```
$prev = ($i >=2) ? $i-1 : FALSE;
$next = ($i < $totalPages) && ($totalPages > 2) ? $i-1 : FALSE;
if ($prev) {
    echo '<a href="/lefthanddrivecars/result.php?marque='.$marque.'&amp;modele='.$modele.'&amp;budgetInit='.$budgetInit.'&amp;budgetFinal='.$budgetFinal.'&amp;nrj='.$nrj.'&amp;bv='.$bv.'&amp;cat='.$cat.'&amp;kmInit='.$kmInit.'&amp;kmFinal='.$kmFinal.'&amp;annee='.$annee.'&amp;nbinit='.$nbinit2.'">'.$prev.'</a> ';
}

if ($page == $i) {
    echo $i;
}

if ($next) {
    echo '<a href="/lefthanddrivecars/result.php?marque='.$marque.'&amp;modele='.$modele.'&amp;budgetInit='.$budgetInit.'&amp;budgetFinal='.$budgetFinal.'&amp;nrj='.$nrj.'&amp;bv='.$bv.'&amp;cat='.$cat.'&amp;kmInit='.$kmInit.'&amp;kmFinal='.$kmFinal.'&amp;annee='.$annee.'&amp;nbinit='.$nbinit2.'">'.$next.'</a> ';      
}
```

Comment: oh thanks!ok will try this out, would you add the table and paragraph to it?

Comment: I  dont know where to put it, I'm used to doing basic php codes sorry

Comment: Please go through this tutorial: https://www.myprogrammingtutorials.com/create-pagination-with-php-and-mysql.html

Comment: thanks, I just dont know where to put the a href correctly?